# In how many ways can the subsets $X$ and $Y$ of set $A$ be chosen to satisfy the following expression $|(X/Y)\cup (Y/X)|=1$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A=${$a_1,a_2,...,a_n$}. In how many ways can the subsets $X$ and $Y$ of set $A$ be chosen to satisfy the following expression $|(X/Y)\cup (Y/X)|=1$? I think that we can break the problem into specific cases; so, firstly, we can put no element in set $X$ ($\binom{n}{0}$ ways) and put one element in set $Y$ ($\binom{n}{1}$ ways). But I can't figure out the case when  $|X|=1$ and can't go further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every element except one must belong to both or none.

There are $n$ ways to pick the element which only belongs to one set.

After this, for each other element we have $2$ options (it can belong to both or neither, for the special element we get to decide if w put it in $A$ or $B$.

So the answer is $n2^n$.

Comment: I got your explanation. Now, I'd like to know what the answer would be if we require the following 1) there are 2 or more elements in subset X 2) there are 2 or more elements in subsets X  and Y

Comment: hint: its easier to count the ones that don't satisfy condition $1$ and subtract them to $n2^n$. Although if you want a more detailes solution I would encourage you to post a different question.